# V4L2 and Aptina sensor with external trigger - discard old frames

Tags: c, embedded-linux, v4l2, imx6

I'm using an Aptina MT9V024 sensor connected via LVDS to the CSI interface of an i.MX6 Quad. I'm running the sensor in snapshot mode, i.e. using an external signal to trigger/start the image capture.

On software side, I'm running Yocto Linux and an application written in C which should retrieve the captured image data.

It works like this (part of the code, run in a loop):

```
// wait until camers is triggered
ret = select(video_fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

// dq buffer / read image data and save to disk
ret = xioctl(video_fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &v4l2buf);
img->imageData = buffers[v4l2buf.index].start;
cvSaveImage(filename, img, 0);

// enqueue another buffer to capture next frame
ret = xioctl(video_fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &v4l2buf);
```

The call to `select(...)` blocks until a new frame is available, i.e. the camera was triggered.

**My problem: The image retrieved is the one from the *previous* capture.** During init, I'm requesting two buffers, because the sensor does not start with less.  But I cannot DQBUF more than one buffer after select(...) returns. So, I'm always stuck with an old frame.

What works is accessing not the buffer which I get returned by DQBUF, but "the other" buffer, i.e. use `buffers[(v4l2buf.index + 1) % 2]` instead of  `buffers[v4l2buf.index]` in the third line in the code above. But I suppose that this is not a very reliable way, as I'm accessing a buffer which is, according to the v4l2 API, not ready to be read (but in reality it contains the data which I want).

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same problem, and the customer service weren't able to help me so far (but still trying).